# Bundle javascript files in react with using next.js for loading page performance

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, seo, pageload

I work with an SEO consultant for SEO optimizations and faster page loading. He said that too many individual JS is being called. This will delay the loading of the site. For this, it is the right alternative to make a single BUNDLE. i need to do it as 1 or 2 BUNDLE must OPTIMIZE according to which one gives better performance. my hierarchy and chucked js as follow after build ; I also searched about webpack but I could not adapt the codes I found, as follow the [page of next js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) related to webpack. I  added this and nothing changed.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    // Note: we provide webpack above so you should not `require` it
    // Perform customizations to webpack config
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//))

    // Important: return the modified config
    return config
  },
}
```

I also use next js for server side rendering. Other picture shows my structure in the react project and  i think i should refer config to index js. maybe. How i should forward to solve my problem ? If you need any other information, i will try to write it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Next.js already optimizes the client bundle for best performance. It's always a good idea to use [`@next/bundle-analyzer`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-bundle-analyzer) and analyze where improvements could be made. Another option is to look into [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) to load modules on-demand and reduce the initial client bundle.

Comment: Hi @juliomalves, thanks for your answer. i m gonna try it you wrote but before trying,  i wanna ask you something that my project is hosted in azure app service,i deploy in vs code to use azure extension and choose the app service then right click  deploy to web app and it is deployed. i did my deploy as always like this but i realized both of these environments are loading different. prod mode is loading more javascript than working localhost. Do you know something about this matter ?

Comment: What if you run the prod build locally? You can do so by running `yarn build && yarn start`.

Comment: you mean, next.js already chunks js and it is not possible to bundle js files,

Comment: It's still possible, but you'll have to mess around with the webpack config in your `next.config.js` at your own discretion.

Comment: I already tried something found on the internet and couldnt adopt it? Can you help me about it? If you need info, i can edit my post for your request. I ll be glad if you help